# Присвоить разные значения из одного массива

Tags: массивы, swift, xcode, дата, календарь

Я пытаюсь сделать календарь используя Pod 'CalendarKit'. Мне нужно, чтобы разные строки из одного массива присваивалась к **event.text**.
Массив выглядит так:

```
var data = [["Завтрак",
               "Яйцо"],

              ["Обед",
               "Мясо"],

              ["Ужин",
               "Курица"]]
```

Я пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом:

```
for i in 0 ..< data.count {
            event.text = data[i].joined(separator: "\n")
            print(i, " ", data[i]) ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]
                                   ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]
                                   ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]
                                   ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]
                                   ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]
                                   ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]
                                   ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]
                                   ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]
                                   ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]
                                   ///0   ["Завтрак", "Яйцо"]
                                   ///1   ["Обед", "Мясо"]
                                   ///2   ["Ужин", "Курица"]

        }
```

Но по итогу в календаре я получаю повторение только последней строки **"Ужин", "Курица"**
[image: Повторение только последней строки **"Ужин", "Курица"**]
Как я могу присвоить разные значения к событию в календаре? Ниже предоставляю код всей функции. Заранее спасибо

```
override func eventsForDate(_ date: Date) -> [EventDescriptor] {
    var date = date.add(TimeChunk.dateComponents(hours: Int(arc4random_uniform(1) + 10)))
    var events = [Event]()

    for i in 0...4 {
      let event = Event()
      let duration = Int(arc4random_uniform(1) + 60)
      let datePeriod = TimePeriod(beginning: date,
                                  chunk: TimeChunk.dateComponents(minutes: duration))

      event.startDate = datePeriod.beginning!
      event.endDate = datePeriod.end!




        for i in 0 ..< data.count {
            event.text = data[i].joined(separator: "\n")
            print(i, " ", data[i])
        }
```

Ниже код полность:

```
import UIKit
import CalendarKit
import DateToolsSwift

enum SelectedStyle {
  case Dark
  case Light
}

class ExampleController: DayViewController, DatePickerControllerDelegate {

  var data = [["Завтрак",
               "Яйцо"],

              ["Обед",
               "Мясо"],

              ["Ужин",
               "Курица"]]

  var colors = [UIColor.blue,
                UIColor.yellow,
                UIColor.green,
                UIColor.red]

  var currentStyle = SelectedStyle.Light

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "CalendarKit Demo"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Dark",
                                                        style: .done,
                                                        target: self,
                                                        action: #selector(ExampleController.changeStyle))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Change Date",
                                                        style: .plain,
                                                        target: self,
                                                        action: #selector(ExampleController.presentDatePicker))
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    dayView.autoScrollToFirstEvent = true
    reloadData()
  }

  @objc func changeStyle() {
    var title: String!
    var style: CalendarStyle!

    if currentStyle == .Dark {
      currentStyle = .Light
      title = "Dark"
      style = StyleGenerator.defaultStyle()
    } else {
      title = "Light"
      style = StyleGenerator.darkStyle()
      currentStyle = .Dark
    }
    updateStyle(style)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.title = title
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = style.header.backgroundColor
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:style.header.swipeLabel.textColor]
    reloadData()
  }

  @objc func presentDatePicker() {
    let picker = DatePickerController()
    picker.date = dayView.state!.selectedDate
    picker.delegate = self
    let navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: picker)
    navigationController?.present(navC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func datePicker(controller: DatePickerController, didSelect date: Date?) {
    if let date = date {
      dayView.state?.move(to: date)
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // MARK: EventDataSource

  override func eventsForDate(_ date: Date) -> [EventDescriptor] {
    var date = date.add(TimeChunk.dateComponents(hours: Int(arc4random_uniform(1) + 10)))
    var events = [Event]()

    for i in 0...4 {
      let event = Event()
      let duration = Int(arc4random_uniform(1) + 60)
      let datePeriod = TimePeriod(beginning: date,
                                  chunk: TimeChunk.dateComponents(minutes: duration))

      event.startDate = datePeriod.beginning!
      event.endDate = datePeriod.end!




        for i in 0 ..< data.count {
            event.text = data[i].joined(separator: "\n")
            print(i, " ", data[i])
        }







      // Event styles are updated independently from CalendarStyle
      // hence the need to specify exact colors in case of Dark style
      if currentStyle == .Dark {
        event.textColor = textColorForEventInDarkTheme(baseColor: event.color)
        event.backgroundColor = event.color.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
      }

      events.append(event)

      let nextOffset = Int(arc4random_uniform(250) + 40)
      date = date.add(TimeChunk.dateComponents(minutes: nextOffset))
      event.userInfo = String(i)
    }

    return events
  }

  private func textColorForEventInDarkTheme(baseColor: UIColor) -> UIColor {
    var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
    baseColor.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a)
    return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s * 0.3, brightness: b, alpha: a)
  }

  // MARK: DayViewDelegate

  override func dayViewDidSelectEventView(_ eventView: EventView) {
    guard let descriptor = eventView.descriptor as? Event else {
      return
    }
    print("Event has been selected: \(descriptor) \(String(describing: descriptor.userInfo))")
  }

  override func dayViewDidLongPressEventView(_ eventView: EventView) {
    guard let descriptor = eventView.descriptor as? Event else {
      return
    }
    print("Event has been longPressed: \(descriptor) \(String(describing: descriptor.userInfo))")
  }

  override func dayView(dayView: DayView, willMoveTo date: Date) {
    print("DayView = \(dayView) will move to: \(date)")
  }

  override func dayView(dayView: DayView, didMoveTo date: Date) {
    print("DayView = \(dayView) did move to: \(date)")
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста весь код метода.

Comment: @ВикторМишустин, добавил код полностью. Также оставляю  [ссылку](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit) на все демо-приложение которое я пытаюсь исправить под себя. В нем события в календаре формируются рандомно.